# Find the area enclosed by the curve and the chord $AB$.

Tags: geometry, definite-integrals

Let $f(x)=\frac{-1}{4}x^2+1$.Let $V$ be the point on the curve $y=f(x)$ whose ordinate have the greatest value and $A$ be the point of intersect of the curve with the with the negative side of the $x$ axis.The chord $AB$ of the curve subtends a right angle at $V$.Find the area enclosed by the curve and the chord $AB$.

When i solved this question.I found $V=(0,1)$ and $A=(-2,0)$ and VA and VB are perpendicular,thus $B$ comes out to be $x=8$.Whether my B is correct or not.I am not sure.I cannot solve it further.Answer given in the book is $41\frac{2}{3}$.Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertice $(0,1)$ is the point of the curve where the ordinate is maximum. Now, 
let $\left(b,-\frac{1}{4}b^2+1\right)$ the coordinates of $B$, since $\angle AVB$ is right 
\begin{align}
m_{AV}m_{VB}&=-1\\[4pt]
\frac{1-0}{0-(-2)}\cdot\frac{-\frac{1}{4}b^2+1-1}{b-0}&=-1\\[4pt]
\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{-b}{4}&=-1\\[2pt]
b&=8
\end{align}
It follows that $B$ has coordinates $(8,-15)$, we must find the equation of the line $AB$:
\begin{align}
y-y_1&=m(x-x_1)\\
y-0&=\left\{\frac{-15-0}{8-(-2)}\right\}[x-(-2)]\\[3pt]
y&=-\frac{3}{2}(x+2)
\end{align}
The area enclosed between the curve $y=-\frac{1}{4}x^2+1$ and the chord $AB$ can be found using an integral:
\begin{align}
\text{Area }&=\int_{-2}^8\left\{-\frac{1}{4}x^2+1-\left[-\frac{3}{2}(x+2)\right]\right\}\,dx
\end{align}